# How do I implement a static library from libPusher in Objective-C (Xcode 4.2)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

## Please show me how I can add and implement the libPusher library to my Objective-C iOS project

### This is my first post on StackOverflow

I've just started working in Objective-C iOS app development for a company that I co-founded with a couple of colleagues. Our first app needs to have the libPusher library implemented in its porject. Right now, I'm at a crossroads completing the following task of adding and implementing it on Xcode 4.2:

- Simply copy libPusher-combined.a and the contents of the headers directory into your Xcode project..

Source: http://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher/wiki/Adding-libPusher-to-your-project

What does it mean by "*copy*"ing those files, and where should it be copied to? Can anybody who has experience with libPusher give me specific details as a list and source code on how to execute this so I can understand it better? I would truly appreciated any help, it will get our company up and running for us getting our app functioning and ready for reviewing submission to Apple Developer staff. The link I've provided will tell you more on what I'm talking about, if I need to specify anything I'll create a new post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What "copy" means in this context is that you want to drag and drop the .a (library) file *and* the header files (all the .h files) into your new Xcode project (to be precise: the file inspector is the list of files along the left side of the workspace window).

Answer (score 0):

To copy anything to an Xcode project, find it in the finder, highlight all of the files you want to copy over (or just take the folder it comes in), then drag everything over the Xcode icon in the dock.

If Xcode is full screen (lion), the icon will kind of blink, then enter Mission Control mode, you then hold the files over the correct project and drop them into the Xcode file tree.

## Make sure that your application is checked as a target for those files!!

If Xcode is not full screen, just drag the files or folder into the Xcode file tree and they will be added.

To link to a static library, just navigate to the name of your project>Info>Framworks.  Click the plus, then select your framework if it isn't already there.